# Is there a tool to automate all these steps in Mac OSX something like ant?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am following this tut
http://monoclestudios.com/cocos2d_whitepaper.html

to integrate coco2sd. I have created a project, modified the sources, added external directory to project, delete some files within and added coco2sd to proect as they requested.

There are a lot more to do by hands.

If I had to do it again oh my, so is there a tool to automate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible — although not exactly easy - to [add your own new project templates to Xcode](http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/04/cocoa-dev-design-your-own-xcode-project-templates.ars).

Comment: Thanks that's helpfull. Is there anything else to also automate build and deployment ?